# check editText with arraylist and not let user to enter the same data

Tags: android, listview

User can add product & qty from `EditText` , which gets displayed in `ListView`  on ADD button pressed, now i don't want user to enter the same product again..fetched data from DB... Need help,find code below!

```
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                    String nullProduct = product.getText().toString();
                     nullQuant = quantity.getText().toString();

                    if (nullProduct.matches("") || nullQuant.matches("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(InvoiceView.this, "Please choose Product and Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    } else {

                        quant = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());      // Calculation of quantity + unit price
                        unitprice = Double.parseDouble(prounitprice);
                        result = quant * unitprice;
                        Result = String.valueOf(result);
                                                // Total value of sales order
                        Map<String, String> dataFinal = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        dataFinal.put("A", proname);
                        dataFinal.put("B", String.valueOf(quant));
                        dataFinal.put("C", String.valueOf(unitprice));
                        dataFinal.put("D", Result);
                        proFinal.add(dataFinal);

                        String[] from = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
                        int[] listviews = {R.id.lblproname, R.id.lblproqty, R.id.lblprorate, R.id.lblprototal};
                        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(InvoiceView.this,
                                proFinal, R.layout.lsttemplate, from,
                                listviews);
                        lstpro.setAdapter(ADA);

                        int count = proFinal.size();
                        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                            HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) proFinal.get(i);
                            String sValue;
                            if (proFinal.size() > 1) {
                                sValue = map.get("A");
                                if (nullProduct.equals(sValue)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(InvoiceView.this, "Product already added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                             // incomplete code section

                                }
                            }
                        }
                        }                      
                        product.setText("");
                        quantity.setText("");

                }
            });

    }
```

Comment: get data from `EditText` and then compare with your `ArrayList` Elements

Answer (score 0):

Save product name as unique key in hash map. Compare the map key's with entered product, if the map does not have your entered product as a key then save it. Otherwise show message like "Product already exists..!!".

try below code:

```
  Map<String, String> dataFinal = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dataFinal.put("A", "name");
    dataFinal.put("B", "String.valueOf(quant)");
    dataFinal.put("C", "String.valueOf(unitprice)");
    dataFinal.put("D", "Result");

    for (int i = 0; i < dataFinal.size(); i++) {
        String yourEnteredProduct = "D";//Assume new product D which is already existed,so you should not save it
        if (!dataFinal.containsKey(yourEnteredProduct)) {
            //Save you newly entered product
        } else {
            //Product already exists
        }
    }
```

Hope it will help you.